# How to identify too small network in reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am using [Open AI's](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/actor_critic.py) code to do a RL task on an environment that I built myself.

I tried some network architectures, and they all converge, faster or slower on CartPole.

On my environment, the policy seems not to converge, and the reward per episode , or even the average reward per episode keeps flickering forever.

I suspect the neural network is too small, but I want to confirm my belief before going the route of researching the architecture.

How can I confirm that the architecture is the problem and not anything else in a neural network reinforcement learning task?